# python iterate mongo nested object list

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x

I am fetching nested record from mongodb using query

```
@classmethod
def fetch_links(self, web_id):
cursor = self.db.websites.find({"_id": ObjectId(web_id)}, {"links": 1})
    results = list(cursor)
    return results
```

and I am calling this function as:

```
old_links = Signatures.fetch_links(web_id)
    print(old_links)
```

and gettin result as:

```
[{
'_id': ObjectId('5ac5efd6a37efa4c0e28f5aa'),
'links': [{
    'type': 'np',
    'link_id': 'quotes-1',
    'link': '/'
}, {
    'type': 'np',
    'link_id': 'quotes-2',
    'link': '/login'
},  {
    'type': 'np',
    'link_id': 'redcarpetsupport-1',
    'link': 'AR/index.html'
}, {
    'type': 'np',
    'link_id': 'redcarpetsupport-3',
    'link': 'services.html'
}]
```

}]

Now I would like to access  like:

```
print(old_links['link']), old_links(links['link_id']) and print(old_links['type'])
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `links` coming from? Well you iterate each of `results` right? So within each `result` ( which I presume you named `links` for some reason ) you simply iterate each of the `link` property contained within i.e `for links in results: for link in links['links']: #do something` or however you want to iterate lists

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" using for link in old_links['links']: and print(link['type'])
KeyError: 'type' while using for link in old_links:    
  print(link['link'])
Actually I am getting different format of result. I updated the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. How about updating your question with the actual full code you are using. You don't seem to be following what I am saying, so you need to actually show us.

Comment: @NeilLunn, Sorry for making you confused. I updated the original post with the exact output.

Comment: Still confused `print(links` there is no `links` in your code. You only show code as far as returning `results`. So I'm asking for the rest of the code after that

Comment: links is the variable in which I assigning function now changed to old_links. I again updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by convertine list to array and looping twice inside for. I don't know whether it is good nor not.

```
import numpy as np

old_links = Signatures.fetch_level1_links(web_id)
link_arr = np.array(old_links)

for item in link_arr:
    #print(item['links'])
    for link in item['links']:
        print(link['type'])
```